# Update All Views after Localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I am developing an application which contains localization within app.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Using this above code app's default language is changed but I can't update all views

I have created two strings file one for English and one for Arabic. and its changes device language using above code. i have change my language from english to Arabic, but not update all views at that time. but when i restart my app, then tabbar an uitableview changes its position from "Left to right" to "right to left" in arabic. But i have to update this without restarting the app.

Comment: your question is too broad. Changing the device language doesn't change the language of your app. You need to have the localizable.strings file for your app content.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I have created two strings file one for English and one for Arabic. and its changes device language using above code. i have change my language from english to Arabic, but not update all views at that time. but when i restart my app, then tabbar an uitableview changes its position from "Left to right" to "right to left" in arabic. But i have to update this without restarting the app.